# We throw a die 5 times probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We throw a die $5$ times, what is the probability of throwing $6$ three consecutive times but not four consecutive times?

**My thought process:**

We know that the probability of a die showing $6$ is $\frac{1}{6}$, that the die shows any other number is $\frac{5}{6}$.

{$666XX$} the probability for the sequence of throws on the left would be: $\frac{1}{6^3}\cdot \frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}$.

Then the probability for the sequence of throws {$X666X$}: $\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6^3}\cdot\frac{5}{6}$

And then with the last sequence we get: $\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{6^3}$.

We can use the theorem that $P(A\cap B)= \{\}\implies P(A\cup B)= P(A)+P(B)$

If I sum them all together I get clearly a wrong answer.

The solution should be:

$$\frac{1 \cdot 1\cdot 1 \cdot 5 \cdot 6}{6^5}+\frac{5\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot5}{6^5}+\frac{6\cdot5\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1}{6^5}=\frac{85}{7776}=0.0109.$$

However, I do not understand how to get to this solution.

Comment: In your first step, you appear to exclude $666X6$, though the rules would appear to call that a win.  Similarly, I suppose you improperly exclude $6X666$.

Comment: I see, so that's why for example $666X6$, the last number can be anything, thus $\frac{6}{6}$. But still, the solution only has three summations while my solution would have $5$ if I would also include those two cases.

Comment: It's because one of their cases is $666XA$, where $X\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $A\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. This covers two of your cases.

Comment: @DonThousand I see, so with this addition my thought process was correct.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Note that your original computation correctly answers the question "what is the probability that, out of five tosses of a fair die, you will get three $6's$ in a row *and no other $6's$*?".  Of course, that is not the question you were asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sequence

$$X-X-6-6-6$$

the first occurrence can be any number, thus with probability 1.

The same happens in the sequence $6-6-6-X-X$ for the last occurrence.

the probability of these two sequences is

$$1\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6^3}$$

while for the second sequence you showed you have a probability of

$$\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6^3}\cdot\frac{5}{6}$$

thus the total probability is

$$2\cdot\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6^3}+\frac{5}{6}\cdot \frac{1}{6^3}\cdot\frac{5}{6}=\frac{85}{7776}$$